# How can I stop my function from looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I have an HTML and JS code that makes few input tags on the page (text boxes). Those boxes appear when I press the buttons on the screen (just some JS configuration (playing with `hide()`, `show()` and `append()`)).

Well, I wanted them to append their value to some tags in HTML when I press specific button on the screen. So I did. But I can't make them do that by pressing "Enter" and the "arrow enter" (mobile devices).

I tried `.keyup()`, but that does the thing only if the boxes are static, but I gave them the option to appear and disappear. (In the beginning I press a button - one appends to HTML with another 2 buttons (first to hide it, second is like "enter")). Pressing enter doesn't help when they are dynamic.

Well, I need this "enter" functionality (better on `keyup()` some how).

I've tried this code:

```
$(document).keyup(function() {
    $('#myText').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert("Enter pressed");
        }
    });
});
```

Then:

```
$(function () {
    $('#myText').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert("Enter pressed");
        }
    });
});

$(#myText).keyup(function() {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert("Enter pressed");
    }
});
```

and many others.
It works only on static ones.

Comment: Use event delegation... also ID of an element must be unique.... so use a common class for the input instead of duplicated id

Comment: Are you just looking for delegated event handlers? Did you read the documentation.

Comment: Ids are unique. Well, they didn't help. (Event handlers)